# is there in python library's to drop rows with two conditions without loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem that I can not solve,

I have a Dataframe of size greater than 150000, I want to delete the lines when ID to several Key, it erases lines with the Key "X" if it has others keys than the Key X, it leaves the lines if the id has only key X, you know the libraries in python who can do that, without going through if or loop condition, thanks

Edit :

**if the id has only the key X that's keep it , if the id has multiple values , it's delete only rows which have X as key for this id**

Example :

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuPbV.png)

What I need :

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbdTl.png)

You notice that's "2    B   X" was deleted

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why does 'B X' get deleted, but not 'A X' ?

Comment: Sorry , I inverse the situations , I wanna to keep A X because A don't have another key different than X , and delete B X because there's X and others Key

Comment: Welcome to SO; please notice that question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `bigdata` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Sorry for you @desertnaut but I do this to apply my perceptron in this Dataframe.

Comment: This is irrelevant. Please notice that tags are about the *content* of the question, not its context; the fact that you may need help in debugging, say, a computer vision algorithm to be subsequently used in a spaceship does not qualify a question as being about `space-engineering`.

Comment: Sorry , it was my first time , thank's

Answer (score 0):

First find IDs which have multiple unique Keys:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Key':['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']})

g = df.groupby('ID')['Key'].nunique()
multiple_keys = list(g[g > 1].index)

print(multiple_keys)
```

Output:

```
['B']
```

Now use this to filter your DataFrame:

```
result = df[~((df['ID'].isin(multiple_keys)) & (df['Key'] == 'X'))]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
  ID Key
0  A   X
1  A   X
3  B   Y
4  B   Z
```

Comment: Thank You @Dan ! 